# sqlite search query for finding a particular data from column?

Tags: android

I am making app for finding number plates of india.
my database contains two columnns "code" and "city" code contains data like MH1,MH2 etc.
and city contains data like Pune,Mumbai.

App contains one edittext box and listview.

Listview consists whole data from database like GJ3 Rajkot, GJ10 Jamnagar etc.

if i write GJ in edittext box  whole only data of GJ must be apperaed in listview.

Comment: use text watcher for EditText and when text changes then execute your query in database and in query use "like" incited of "="

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting your ans, can u write a query ?

Comment: [see this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

Comment: not working..coz i have already use one cursor for fetching data from database...and added to the list view..so how can i use another cursor for searching data using edittext and display data in listview accordoing to code typed in editttext

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query : 
 SELECT *
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `code` LIKE '%GJ%'
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Thank You...But my column contains AN,AP,MH,GJ,PB and all states for that wt i have to write ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(
            "select * from table_name where column_name = ?",
            new String[] { "search" });
```

**EDIT :**

Follow the tutorial of the given above link and add below method into TestAdapter

```
public Cursor get_tag_Data()
 {
     try
     {
         String sql ="select * from table_name where column_name = ?", new String[] { edittext.getText().toString().trim()}";

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }
         return mCur;
     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }
 }
```

and call this method from your class like:

```
 TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(urContext);        
 mDbHelper.createDatabase();      
mDbHelper.open();

Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.get_tag_Data();

mDbHelper.close();
```

**EDIT:**

Declare below method into your database class,

```
 public List<String> getQuestions(String difficulty) {

   public static List<String> question_Set;
    question_Set = new ArrayList<String>();


    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(
            "select * from table_name where column_name = ?", new String[] { difficulty });

    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        question_Set.add(c.getString(1).trim());


    }

    return question_Set;
}
```

Now call like

```
DB.getQuestions(edittext.getText().toString().trim()); // DB is your database class name
```

Comment: I think you want to search as per edittext value into column.if yes then put your edittext value in place of search. like `"select * from table_name where column_name = ?",
            new String[] { edittext.getText().toString().trim()}`

Comment: still i am not getting. If i write AP in edittext then in listview it must display a list of AP's city and code.

Comment: How are you accessing the database code?, I don't know. But check this link for the database http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/1263679 I think it's help you.

Comment: not working..coz i have already use one cursor for fetching data from database...and added to the list view..so how can i use another cursor for searching data using edittext and display data in listview accordoing to code typed in editttext

Comment: @PavanAnadkat please check my updated code and follow the http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/1263679

Comment: i have to add a new class Test Adapter ??

Comment: I am edit code for the given link, in that already create the testAdapter class. but no problem if you are going different way then add this method where you already create first cursor query and call same as previous one.

Comment: Please can you show me how you are coding for the first cursor?

Comment: i am enable to search a data from database for example if i write AR in edittext it display all records of AR but it display only in Log cat...Whenever i type anything in Edittext box Listview is diappeared..now i want to display the same data which displays in logcat

Comment: if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {
      String code = cursor.getString(0);
      String city = cursor.getString(1);
      
      Log.d("testdata", code + "" + city);
      arrayList.add(code + "\t" + ":" + "" + city);
      //arrayList.add(data);

      arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
      adapter.clear();
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());

Comment: if you have no problem then accept answer as true or if possible then give upvote.